# How to make a tweak which respring the device?

Tags: theos

I try to make a tweak which  respring the device with theos?
And not with "system("killall -9 SpringBoard");" command.

Comment: Don't know if you're still looking but you could try using `posix_spawn`

Comment: yea I was.... Thanks mate :)